# Check if user has chosen a value from many to many field

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I have a page where a User has to register and after the first login he is offered to choose a few things but only if he hasn't already chosen something. How can I check whether or not there is a value in the automatically generated db table for the current user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ManyToMany fields are attached to the instance as a special manager, but it respects most of the standard manager API.  So for model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    cars = models.ManyToMany(Car)
```

To find out if a person instance has any cars:

```
# Most pythonic
person.cars.exists()

# or
person.cars.count() == 0
```